# Strange segfault when running node on raspberry pi 3

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have recently installed ROS kinetic on a raspberry pi 3 (raspbian jessie), as explained in this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi).

Everything worked fine (except rviz, but I don't need it). However, when I wanted to test some C++ nodes I wrote on my laptop, it didn't worked.

I just copied my packages in the raspi's catkin_ws, then catkin_maked it. I didn't meet any problem when compiling. The python-coded nodes worked fine, but not the C++ ones. Then I tried to make a very simple C++ node saying hello world, and I build it the same way. And it didn't work (Segmentation Fault). Then I discovered, that if, in the CMakeLists, I did not link the catkin/opencv libraries (with `target_link_libraries`, which worked on my laptop), the program worked well, but it obviously couldn't interact with ROS/opencv.

Would you have any suggestion, feel free to answer ;)

Thanking you in advance

**EDIT**

I have included the codes below. The nodes aims at reading a webcam and sending OpenCV images. It works on my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04, ROS kinetic).

Here is the code :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialization of ROS node and ROS topic
    ros::init(argc, argv, "i_Camera");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("/sensors/camera", 1);
    int cam = 0;
    nh.param<int>("camera_id",cam,0);

    cv::VideoCapture cap(cam);
    // Check if video device can be opened with the given index
    if(!cap.isOpened()) return 1;
    cv::Mat frame;
    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg;

    ros::Rate loop_rate(60);
    
    // Main loop, grab frames and publish them on the topic
    while (nh.ok()) {
        cap >> frame;
        // Check if grabbed frame is not empty
        if(!frame.empty()) {
            msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8, frame).toImageMsg();
            pub.publish(msg);
            cv::waitKey(1);
        }

        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

And the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(vision)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    geometry_msgs
    roscpp
    rospy
    std_msgs
    visualization_msgs
    image_transport
    cv_bridge
    )

find_package(OpenCV)

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    #  LIBRARIES vision
    CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs visualization_msgs image_transport cv_bridge
    #  DEPENDS system_lib
    )

include_directories(
    include
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

add_executable(i_Camera src/i_Camera.cpp)

target_link_libraries(i_Camera
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241494/strange-segfault-when-running-node-on-raspberry-pi-3/) by [roach](https://answers.ros.org/users/27720/roach/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2016-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not a direct answer, but maybe some things to try:

- Does segfault on any particular line of code?
- I didn't use rasbian or OpenCV, so this might be complete miss, but maybe try Ubuntu Mate 16.04? It should correspond more closely to what you have on laptop? I have a lot of ROS stuff running or RPi3 with Ubuntu without issues.

Marcin

---

Originally posted by [Marcin Bogdanski](https://answers.ros.org/users/26406/marcin-bogdanski/) with karma: 231 on 2016-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roach](https://answers.ros.org/users/27720/roach/) on 2016-08-11**:
Thank you very much for your answer !

Segfault happens when running the node, and I think while loading libraries in memory. I have tried to print something before doing anything else, but it also segfaults.

I'll try Ubuntu Mate right now and keep you informed.

**Comment by [roach](https://answers.ros.org/users/27720/roach/) on 2016-08-18**:
I have tried with Ubuntu Mate, and it works very well, using exactly the same codes.